# DB2 9.5 CREATE DATABASE fails with Error SQL0901N, SQLSTATE 58004

Tags: db2

Installed DB2 on Windows Vista with Admin priviledges.
Now i cannot create any new databases.. it always fails with the following error:

db2 CREATE DATABASE N3000 AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES  ON 'D:\DB2'
 DBPATH ON 'D:\DB2'
SQL0901N  Die SQL-Anweisung schlug aufgrund eines nicht schwer wiegenden
(nicht kritischen) Systemfehlers fehl. Nachfolgende SQL-Anweisungen können
verarbeitet werden. (Ursachencode: "Length in PD=0, LFD length=1176, DMS
length=1176".)  SQLSTATE=58004

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

in db2 directory:

c:\program files\ibm\sqllib\bin

execute:

db2set DB2_CREATE_DB_ON_PATH=YES
db2stop
db2start

Ready, now you create DB2 Databases in any path!!!!

look this: http://www.db2ude.com/?q=node/54

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by an antivirus policy and was unrelated to DB2.
The file "C0000000.CAT" has to be excluded.